# How to Register a Name in a ValueConverter context?

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

So I have an application in wich I can configure the way I want the application to look like from the app.config. The application contains a user control that I called "Callout" that is used to call the next custumer. I want to animate this usercontrol's background when the next custumer property changes.

I know how to do that, my only problem is that I receive the configurations for it's background on a converter and transform them into a Solid, LinearGradient or RadialGradient Brush. In order to animate the gradient stops I need to Register their names and I don't have access to that method in the Converter.

How can I achieve this effect on the converter? How am I able to register names in it?

The following are the relevant pieces of code:

Part of the configSection located in app.config:

```
<callout key="PacientCallout"
           title="Paciente" 
           placeholder="N/D"
           border="#FFFFC20E">
    <titleFont family="/Clinical.Resources;Component/Fonts/#Dax-Regular"
               size="40"
               isCustom="true">
      <colors type="Solid">
        <color key="TitleColor" code="White" />
      </colors>
    </titleFont>
    <textFont family="/Clinical.Resources;Component/Fonts/#Dax-Regular"
               size="30"
               isCustom="true">
      <colors type="Solid">
        <color key="TextColor" code="White" />
      </colors>
    </textFont>
    <!--Possible values for type are Solid, LinearGradient or RadialGradient--> 
    <background type="LinearGradient">
        <color key="StarBlue" code="#FF2A398C" />
        <color key="EndBlue" code="#FF0D174F" />
    </background>
  </callout>
```

The Border in wich I am placing all the user controls elements:

```
 <Border CornerRadius="30,0,0,30" 
        Margin="0,15,0,15"
        BorderBrush="{Binding Border,
                              Converter={StaticResource StringToBrushConverter},
                              Mode=TwoWay,
                              PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" 
        Background="{Binding Background,
                             Converter={StaticResource StringToGradientStopConverter},
                             Mode=TwoWay,
                             PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
        BorderThickness="2" 
        Width="400" 
        Height="150">
    <Border.Triggers>

    </Border.Triggers>
    <Border.BitmapEffect>
        <DropShadowBitmapEffect Color="Black" 
                                Direction="225" 
                                ShadowDepth="6"
                                Opacity="0.5" />
    </Border.BitmapEffect>

    <!-- More User Control stuff in here -->

    </Border>
```

And the converter for the background configs into brush:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)(DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject)).DefaultValue))
            return null;

        var gradient = value as Clinical.Core.Configuration.ColorCollection;
        double offset = 0;
        Brush brush;
        switch (gradient.Type)
        {
            case BackgroundType.Solid:
                brush = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(gradient[0].Code);
                break;
            case BackgroundType.LinearGradient:
                LinearGradientBrush linearGradient = new LinearGradientBrush();
                linearGradient.StartPoint = new Point(0.5, 0);
                linearGradient.EndPoint = new Point(0.5, 1);
                linearGradient.MappingMode = BrushMappingMode.RelativeToBoundingBox;

                foreach (Clinical.Core.Configuration.ColorElement color in gradient)
                {
                    var colorCode = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(color.Code);
                    var gradientStop = new GradientStop(colorCode, offset);
                    linearGradient.GradientStops.Add(gradientStop);
                    offset += 1d / ((double)gradient.Count-1);
                }
                brush = linearGradient;
                break;
            case BackgroundType.RadialGradient:
                RadialGradientBrush radialGradient = new RadialGradientBrush();
                radialGradient.GradientOrigin = new Point(0.75,0.15);
                radialGradient.MappingMode = BrushMappingMode.RelativeToBoundingBox;
                foreach (Clinical.Core.Configuration.ColorElement color in gradient)
                {
                    var colorCode = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(color.Code);
                    var gradientStop = new GradientStop(colorCode, offset);
                    radialGradient.GradientStops.Add(gradientStop);
                    offset += 1d / ((double)gradient.Count-1);
                }
                brush = radialGradient;
                break;
            default:
                brush = null;
                break;
        }

        return brush;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In your situation the best solutions is to use MultiBinding instead of Binding just like this:

```
   <Border.BorderBrush>
            <MultiBinding Converter="Converter={StaticResource StringToBrushConverter}">
                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    <Binding PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"/>
                    <Binding Path="." ElementName="border" />
                </MultiBinding.Bindings>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
```

By this way you can pass several objects into converter. For example Path="." allows you to pass instance of any control or object. Also note that, instead of IValueConverter, you must implement IMultiValueConverter for MultiBinding. Hope this helped you.

Comment: I think that does not suit my needs because the converter is used on more than one UC and for me to use that approach I would need to pass the UC in the binding in order to have access to the RegisterName method. But I'll explore the approach and provide feedback as soon as I try it.